# google音声認識で、文字入力などで語句や固有名詞の変換結果が同音語彙の場合に、意図した変換候補に変わらない

Tags: android

google音声入力やgoogleアシスタントにおいて、例えば「同音の漢字別表記の有名な人名」と、「そうでないマイナーな人名」では、必ず有名な人名に変換されるのですが、googleの連絡先に　先ほどのマイナーな人名のみを登録した状態で、googleアシスタントで、そのgoogleの連絡先に登録した同音の認識結果であったとしても、有名な人名の漢字別表記となり、googleアシスタントの検索結果は、該当なしとなってしまいます。
パソコンやandroid端末でも　同じ結果となりました。

google日本語入力の学習辞書に語句を登録しても、音声認識の候補が変わることがありませんでした。

googleの連絡先に「先ほどのマイナーな人名」の項目にふりがなと、メモの欄に音声認識での音声と同じよみ、カタカナ、ひらがな、半角と試しても、だめでした。

希望としては、google音声入力で、再変換　個人的変換の優先の変更
googleアシスタントにおいて、googleの連絡先に登録してある人名などで、同音語彙(漢字違い)の方を検索できて、googleアシスタントにおいて「何々さんに、メールして」とか「電話して」とか話した場合、この問題を解決して、複数の候補があれば選べる処理などできるようになればとお願いしたいです。

Answer (score 1):

Google Contacts (連絡先) で「ニックネーム」という項目があるので、(メモ欄ではなく)こちらに呼びかけ時の名前を入力するのがよさそうです。